# My recursive insertion sort program is not working properly

Tags: python, recursion, insertion-sort

Hello guys I am trying to implement insertion recursively but my list is not getting sorted. Any help or improvements are welcome.

```
sequence = [1,4,3,5,7,6,8,2]

def insertion(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        key = seq[i]
        j = i
    print(seq)
    while j > 0 and seq[j-1] > key:
        j = j - 1
        seq[j] == key

insertion(sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code:

- Your indentation is incorrect, fix that first.
- You're missing a statement that should come as the first in the body
  of the `while` loop to assign `seq[j]` to be the element that follows
  it.
- The `seq[j] == key` statement is a no-op -- this is not a `==`
  situation but rather a `=` one.
- Your implementation isn't recursive, so once you get this code working, start over.